# Flux boundary condition in solute transport

Tags: boundary-conditions, comsol

I have a pretty naive question, though important to me.
Usually when solving the following PDE in solute transport:

$\frac{{\partial C}}{\partial t } = \nabla. (D\nabla C -vC )=0,$

one can be asked to use a third-type boundary condition (called flux in software like Comsol or Phreeqc):

$(D\nabla C -vC )=vCo,$

where the left-hand side is assumed to be evaluated at the center of the cell, and the right-hand side represents the inflow or outflow flux (Am I right about this last sentence?)

In some software (Comsol) you do not have to specify Co, therefore I assume that in such cases the boundary condition is reduced to:

$D\nabla C = 0.$

Is that true? Can such boundary condition be considered constant flux boundary conditon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct boundary condition is in fact 
$$
  (D\nabla C - vC) \cdot n = g.
$$
That is, it is not the vector-valued quantity in parentheses that you can describe, but only the *normal* component, where $n$ is the normal vector to the boundary.

The term in the parentheses is called the *flux*. It describes the amount of material (solute) that moves around, and the entire left side of the equation above is the amount of material that flows *across the boundary*. Specifically, if you at an *inflow* boundary condition, and the concentration of your solute on the *outside* of the domain is $C_0$, then $g=(vC_0)\cdot n$ is the correct description.

If, in Comsol, you can't specify a right hand side $g=vC_0$, then I my interpretation would be that that implies that $g=0$, which would mean
$$
  (D\nabla C - vC) \cdot n = 0.
$$
In other words, no material flows across the boundary.